# How to create this slightly complicated XML Drawable in Android?

Tags: android, android-drawable

How can I create this drawable in a XML resource file?
I have tried using a layer-list drawable but I'm having issues scaling the arrow resources.

Is there a simpler approach?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/accent_blue" />
            <size android:width="@dimen/circle_thermostat_diameter_large" android:height="@dimen/circle_thermostat_diameter_large" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/arrow_up" android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>

    <!-- ... -->

</layer-list>
```

[image]

Comment: the question is: why xml?

Comment: Mainly just to reduce code, and have a simple elegant solution.

Comment: in theory you can do it but the vertical offsets of up/down arrows will be fixed (so you cannot place it in for example 1/4 and 3/4 of available height)

Comment: if you want it to adapt to the real Drawable bounds you can use a ShapeDrawable with a custom Shape

Comment: Would you say its better to just use the blue circle as a bg to a RelativeLayout and then position ImageViews of the arrows accordingly with a TextView in the center?

Comment: no, no, no... create a class that extends Shape and pass it to ShapeDrawable constructor

Comment: Can you submit an answer so I have a better idea?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
class S extends Shape {
    Path path = new Path();
    float size;

    S(float size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResize(float width, float height) {
        float radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(width / 2 - size, height / 2 - radius / 2);
        path.rLineTo(size, -size);
        path.rLineTo(size, size);

        path.moveTo(width / 2 - size, height / 2 + radius / 2);
        path.rLineTo(size, size);
        path.rLineTo(size, -size);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
        float w = getWidth();
        float h = getHeight();
        float radius = Math.min(w, h) / 2;
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(w / 2, h / 2, radius, paint);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(size / 4);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

sample code (add it in onCreate):

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
float size = 128;
tv.setTextSize(size);
tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tv.setText("72");
setContentView(tv);
tv.setBackground(new ShapeDrawable(new S(size / 2)));
```

result:

[image]